# Open XML get cells by Column index C#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have found the index of the columns that I want to put into a string to be added to a data grid. I am not sure how to use the index value in Open XML to find the cells that I want.

```
        bool headerIndexComplete = false;
        int a1141Index = -1;
        int NacIndex = -1;

        string fileName = "FilePathHere";

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
                SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
                SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;

                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
                Worksheet sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

                //var cells = sheet.Descendants<Cell>();
                var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>();

                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    int ColumnIndex = 0;

                    foreach (Cell Cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        int ssid = int.Parse(Cell.CellValue.Text);
                        string CellText = sst.ChildElements[ssid].InnerText;

                        if (!headerIndexComplete)
                        {
                            if (CellText == "1141")
                                a1141Index = ColumnIndex;

                            if (CellText == "CHARGE GROUP (NAC'S)")
                                NacIndex = ColumnIndex;

                            ColumnIndex++;
                        }                         
                    }         
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could u plz add example of what you want?, so we clearly understand it and provide u answer

Comment: I would like to get all the cells in the Columns with the headers "1141" and "CHARGE GROUP (NAC'S)" from the excel spreadsheet and add them to a Data Grid View/Data Model with the same name.

Comment: Yes it's possible, I'll add the answer soon :)

Comment: 1141 is the column reference. So is there any header name exist for both of column? If so then could u plz provide those names

Comment: 1141 is the header from the first row which I am using as the column name.